# How to solve this system of equations that appears in a ODE exercise?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I am trying to solve this equation, we know $A, B, Q,\phi\in\mathbb{R}$.

\begin{eqnarray}
 T''(x) &=& \phi (T(x)-Q)    \\
   T(0)&=& A\\ 
   T(b)&=&B
\end{eqnarray}

So the solution will be the sum of a particular solution and a general solution.

By solving $$r^2-\phi=0$$ we have $r=\sqrt{\phi}:=p$

So the general solution has the form:

$$ T(x)= K_1 e^{xp}+K_2 e^{-xp}  $$

If we try a constant, $T_p$, as a particular solution we have

$$0=\phi(T-Q)$$ so

$$T_p=Q$$

Then the solution is

$$T(x) = Q+K_1 e^{xp}+K_2 e^{-xp} $$

Now we apply the condition, so this is the system than I need to solve:
\begin{eqnarray}
 T(x) &=& Q+K_1 e^{xp}+K_2 e^{-xp}     \\
   T(0)&=& A\\ 
   T(b)&=&B
\end{eqnarray}

Where we know $A,B,Q$ and $p$.

so what we need to do is to replace $A$ and $B$

so we have 
\begin{eqnarray}
  A &=& Q+K_1 +K_2      \\
  B &=& Q+K_1 e^{bp}+K_2 e^{-bp} 
\end{eqnarray}

And solve this system to find $K_1$ and $K_2$.

If we use $\cosh(xp)$ and $\sinh(xp)$ notation, I mean

$$T(x) =Q+K_1 e^{xp}+K_2 e^{-xp} $$ generates the same space as

$$T(x)  =Q+C_1 \cosh(xp) + C_2\sinh(xp)$$

so now we can have a little advantage, because:

\begin{eqnarray}
  A &=& Q+C_1      \\
  B &=& Q+C_1 \cosh(bp)+C_2 \sinh(bp) 
\end{eqnarray}

So we have $C_1=A-Q$
and then

$$B-Q=(A-Q)\cosh(bp)-C_2 \sinh(bp)$$

And here is I don´t know how to continue,

1) Is this allowed?

$$C_2=\frac{Q-B+(A-Q)\cosh(bp)}{\sinh(bp)}$$

I mean, are we dividing by zero? 
$$\sinh(x)=0\leftrightarrow e^x=e^{-x}\leftrightarrow x=i\pi n$$

I think in my problem complex numbers are not allowed, so is this correct?

2) if step 1) is correct then we have

$$C_2=\frac{Q-B+(A-Q)\cosh(bp)}{\sinh{bp}}$$

so the solution for $T(x)$ is

$$T(x)=Q+(A-Q)\cosh(xp)+\frac{Q-B+(A-Q)\cosh(bp)}{\sinh(bp)}\sinh(xp)$$
Is there some way to simplify $T(x)$, to some form more cleanly.

3) Now if we change the conditions  to these:

\begin{eqnarray}
  T'(0)&=& A      \\
  T'(b) &=& B 
\end{eqnarray}

How do need to continue? This way(?):
as
$$T(x)  =Q+C_1 \cosh(xp) + C_2\sinh(xp)$$
then 
$$T'(x)= Q +C_1 p\sinh(xp) + C_2 p \cosh(xp)$$

and solve this system(?):
\begin{eqnarray}
  T'(0)&= & A= Q  + C_2 p       \\
  T'(b) &=& B= Q +C_1 p\sinh(bp) + C_2 p \cosh(bp)  
\end{eqnarray}

Help with 1), 2) and 3) please!

Thank you! Sorry for my English!

Comment: $i \pi n=0$ if $n=0$, so $\sinh(0)=0$ but we can consider $p>0$, $b>0$. So $\sinh(bp)\neq 0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solving the equations almost the same way as you did, I have been able to simplify the expression as $$t(x)=Q+\text{csch}(k p) \Big((A-Q) \sinh [p (k-x)]+(B-Q) \sinh [p x] \Big)$$ I hope and wish this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution, but it is almost the same as I have! Thank you again.

Comment: I totally agree ! My contribution was $\epsilon$ or even less !

Answer (score 1):

There is no difficulty if the cases $\phi>0$, then $\phi=0$, then $\phi<0$ are considered successively.

[image]

Comment: I would try to improve this very good answer by re-typing it in a MathJAX appropriate format.